# Require to Pod run as noon-root user

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, nvidia, kubernetes-pod

I want to deploy dcgm-exporter pod as non-root user. 
In values.yaml I made below changes but pod is crashingoff!

Case 1:

```html
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1002
  # capabilities:
  #    add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

```html
kubectl -n kube-system logs dcgm-exporter-6nwvl 
unable to set CAP_SETFCAP effective capability: Operation not permitted
```

Case:2

```html
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  #runAsUser: 1002
  # capabilities:
  #    add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root

Is it possible to change and run as non root user or Is this a requirement for the dcgm-exporter to work as root user?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below. You need SETFCAP Capability.
Please keep Adding the Capabilities which are being reported as required in the log.

```
securityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1002
  capabilities:
    add:
    - "SETFCAP"
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```